# Getting instagram followers via selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I wrote a code to get an account followers. I log in account and go to profile and click follower box and scroll down until at the end withot problem but when i try to get follower's username I have a problem.
I do not get any error but list turns empty. Can you help me? Thanks

```
followers_panel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')
last_ht, ht = 0, 1
while last_ht != ht:
    last_ht = ht
    time.sleep(2)
    # scroll down and retrun the height of scroll
    ht = driver.execute_script(""" 
    arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);
    return arguments[0].scrollHeight; """, followers_panel)

list_of_followers = []

# Extract the follower names
followers = followers_panel.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="PZuss"]')
list_of_followers = []
for follower in followers:
    name = follower.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/span/div').text
    list_of_followers.append(name)
print(list_of_followers)
```

Answer (score 0):

does `followers` get elements? if yes, try out this instead of `for` loop

```
list_of_followers = list(map(lambda x: x.text, driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="PZuss"]//a/span/div')))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But I couldn't get  all followers. I think it is not loaded fully. Could you help me? What can i do?

Comment: For example I got 150 followers but there are 165 followers or same thing in followings..

Comment: @freeengineer it seems instagram prevents web version to load all the followers (bug or feature?), at some point scroll stops working, even on manual scrolling. you may check JS functions there to find the one to load rest of the followers, but as far it's not a simple website, but quite a platform, I had no success to find a solution. a crazy option I could suggest is to run python script from mobile phone (probably Appium would be more handy instead of selenium here), but I've never tried that, so cannot help, unfortunately. OR try chrome extension "IG Exporter" - it'll save followers to csv

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try extensions. I'm really thankful.